# Deciphering a lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I have been following closely, a YouTube video in order to create an on-screen keyboard using tkinter.

I understand most of what is going on; create our buttons within a list and loop through those buttons, inserting rows at the best position to create a good looking keyboard.

The only problem I've been having with this task, is when I click a button, the text of the button gets inserted into an Entry box via tkinter.

The way in which we do this, is to assign a command to the button, and upon pressing it, calls an anonymous function, assigning the button that we pressed to the 'x' parameter. We then pass this parameter to another method and insert the value into the Entry widget.

I'm trying to understand, why can't we just pass in the button itself, but instead we have to assign the button to a parameter...

```
self.textbox = textbox

row=0
col=0

buttons = [
    '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',
    'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p',
    'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',
    'z','x','c','v','b','n','m','end']

for button in buttons:
    # why not the following command instead?
    # command = lambda: self.command(button)
    command = lambda x=button: self.callback(x)
    if button != 'end':
        tk.Button(self, text=button, width=5,
            command=command).grid(row=row, column=col)
    col+=1
    if col > 9:
        col=0
        row+=1

def command(self, button):
    x = button
    self.callback(x)

def callback(self, value):
    self.textbox.insert(tk.END, value)
```

With the above code, I can successfully insert the desired value into my entry widget. However, if we use the code I have commented out, it will instead insert 'end' to the entry widget.

I have tried to replicate the lambda function into a separate method, but I am still inserting an 'end' into my entry widget.

```
# using the commented code above and passing in button as the parameter
def command(self, button):
    x = button
    self.callback(x)

def callback(self, value):
    self.textbox.insert(tk.END, value)
```

I thought If I was able to replicate the function into a non-anon function, then it would work, but clearly it is not.

What exactly is my lambda function doing it and is there a way to replicate it by using a non-anonymous function (ie. method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
for button in buttons:
    command = lambda: self.command(button)
```

is that `command` is equal to `lambda: self.command(button)`, which is passed to the `Button` constructor.
So the command of the `Button` instance is equal to `lambda: self.command(button)`.
You would think that `self.command(button)` is evaluated, and replaced by the result of the following:

```
def command(self, button):
    x = button
    self.callback(x)
```

However, there is no reason to do so: since `self.command(button)` is *inside* of the `lambda` function, it will evaluated *when the* `lambda` *will be called*.

As a consequence, when executing a so created `lambda` function, `button` will be evaluated to the last value it was assigned, *not to the value it had when the* `lambda` *was created*.
Therefore, after that loop, all of those `lamda` functions will have the same behaviour, and the `button` inside of their body will point toward the same `Button` instance.

---

If you want to have a method instead of a `lambda`, you can wrap the `command` method inside of a command builder:

```
def build_command(self, button):
    def command():
        self.callback(button)

    return command
```

Then just call that method to get the expected command:

```
command = self.build_command(button)
```

The reason why this works, is that `button` is then a variable local to `build_command`, and the inner `command` "inherits" this variable into its own local variable dictionary (given by `locals()`).
This local dictionary will stay unaffected by outer changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for this insight. Whilst still very confusing, I should be able to use this information as leverage for whenever I come across lambda's like the ones in my question. This answer, coupled with @sainoba, provide an informative lambda expression rule and how it evaluates variables of the likes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code that shows what **Right leg** is explaining. Python lazily evaluates number:

```
functions1 = []
functions2 = []

for number in range(0,5):
    functions1.append(lambda x=number: print(x))
    functions2.append(lambda : print(number))

for function in functions1:
    function()

for function in functions2:
    function()
```

Because of that the **functions2** only prints 4. While `lambda x=number` evaluates **number** immediately, and set its value to x.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for that insightful answer. Could I please ask why function2 only ever prints 4, and prints it out 4 times?

By my understanding, it should be appending 0-4 in the list, but as you've pointed out, it's only appending 4's; how is this?

Comment: The functions2 list contains lambda functions that will print the value of **number** when they are called.

Since the last value of number was 4, all functions will print 4.